# Check if image content is a valid image code

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.5

Is there any way to check if the image code inside it  is valid  because

some crackers(hackers) can change the extension and play with image info using some applications to trick the website that the type is image while it's not

so  is there any way to check if content is an image code ?

Or is there anyway to check against this type of attacks ?

Comment: IMO, the best approach to this is to have file uploads go to cloud storage like Amazon S3 (support's built in to Laravel for this). Cloud storage like S3 doesn't execute server-side code **ever**; it's about as safe as you can get.

Comment: The app size doesn't need cloud server but it's good idea  currently I'm processing the image using ""Intervention Image""  but I wondered if anyone know another way

Comment: Size really doesn't have anything to do with it. S3 is a cloud service, but doesn't involve managing a server. I've got an app storing images to S3 that costs me $0.03/month as it doesn't get much usage.

Answer (score 2):

For Multiple Images

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'images' => 'required',
    'images.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
]);
```

Single Image Validation

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'image' => 'required',
    'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
]);
```

Comment: Second example should be `'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'`; arrays can't have 2 of the same key (`'image'`), so the first rule `('required')` would be discarded.

Comment: That won't help because mimes can be change including image type.   the only solution for now is for cloud server or  process the image like "Intervention Image"